# What is the best way to store list of 2D coordinates in Qsettings INI file?

Tags: qt, ini, qsettings

I am currently working a project which is dealing with a variable-length list of ROIs(regions of interests -- polygon --), I will have to store it in an INI file via QSettings, I am having problem finding a simple solution which saves the data in a human readable way.

I have tried saving a ROI as array which results in a format like:

```
ROI
ROI/1/x : 1.2  
ROI/1/y : 4.3  
ROI/2/x : 1.5  
ROI/2/y : 7.4  
ROI/3/x : 2.5  
ROI/3/y : 4.3  
ROI/4/x : 9.0  
ROI/4/y : 3.4
```

I am trying to achieve a format like:

```
ROI = [(1.2, 4.3), (1.5, 7.4), (2.5, 4.3), (9.0, 3.4)]
```

Unfortunately, My google foo fails. I have been reading about registering a custom reader/writer to QSettings, But I was wondering if there is a simple way to do it as ROIs and list of 2D Coordinates seems to be widely used for various applications in Qt.

Thanks in advance, Let me know if you would need information about the application.

p.s. Qsetting is not a must, I can use any supported and mature lib.

Comment: That would be pretty easy with the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, but INI format is more readable than json IMHO. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can put your data in a QVariant and then save it in JSON format:

```
QList<QPointF> points;
points << QPointF(1.0, 2.0) << QPointF(3.0, 4.0);

QVariantList points_variant;
foreach(QPointF point, points) {
  points_variant << QVariant(QVariantList() << point.x() << point.y());
}

QByteArray text = QJsonDocument::fromVariant(points_variant).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);
qDebug() << text;
// -> "[[1.1000000000000001,2.2000000000000002],[3.2999999999999998,4.4000000000000004]]"

QList<QPointF> points2;
QVariantList points_variant2 = QJsonDocument::fromJson(text).toVariant().toList();
foreach(QVariant v, points_variant2) {
  QVariantList list = v.toList();
  if (list.count() == 2) {
    points2 << QPointF(list[0].toDouble(), list[1].toDouble());
  }
}
```

Comment: `QByteArray text = QJsonDocument::fromVariant(c).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);` should be `QByteArray text = QJsonDocument::fromVariant(points_variant).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);`, isn't it? thanks for the answer, I think it is the best I can get.
But I am going to try writing custom class for qsettings, if I succeed, I will update here. :)